# Using True-Type Font with aterm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, truetype-fonts

I'd like to use the TTF Consolas with aterm on my Ubuntu system.  I've placed this font in my ~/.fonts directory, and I'm currently using it with emacs and gnome-terminal.  So, I know some applications are recognizing it.  I've added the following lines in my .Xresources:

```
aterm*font:-*-Consolas-Medium-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
aterm*boldFont:-*-Consolas-Bold-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

However, when I start aterm, I get the following message:

```
aterm: can't load font "-*-Consolas-Medium-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
```

Is there something else I need to do to make aterm aware of this font?

Comment: Why not using a more-modern terminal emulator like gnome-terminal or konsole?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, aterm doesn't support TrueType fonts. I'm restating the claim made by people on other Linux support forums, I don't have any ready references right now.

As a long term user of Ubuntu/aterm myself, I've been also trying to get it to use Consolas or Inconsolata fonts. I did spend a fair amount of time tweaking various font settings via fontconfig and such.

BTW, how did you generate the font string above ? xfontsel doesn't list Consolas or Inconsolata. Did you create the string by hand ?